# Repairing gaps between bamboo lock and click floor boards

Tags: flooring

There are several boards with gaps. Some of the boards are uneven. We want to pull the boards together to create one larger gap to put a shim into. When installed the boards were glued together. How can we pull the boards together in order to make this repair

Comment: You are going to break some stuff up should you try to take it apart or even try to tighten it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Glued boards are never going to budge.